# UE4 - Removing Text When Exiting TriggerBox

Tags: text, unreal-engine4, blueprint

Having some trouble getting text to disappear when I exit the trigger box from reading the note. I can easily display the text I want but I am unsure how I can make it disappear when I leave the triggerbox. Blueprint included, any help is appreciated.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Connect GetPlayerController to Create Widget?

Also store the created widget as a variable. It's likely that the widget reference is being lost once the E input event is finished, so the RemoveFromParent node doesn't know what to remove.

For widgets that you're going to use all the time, pre-create them and store them as variables. Much easier to maintain in the long run.